# How to make an analog of "Intead of" trigger in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I need to rewrite insert operation in my sql, to write another value if some condition is true.
For example:

```
Insert into table_name(age) values(2)
```

condition - if age<18, insert 18 instead => age = 18

Comment: Use a `before insert` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `before insert` trigger:

```
create trigger <trigger name> before insert on <table> 
for each row
begin
    set new.age = least(new.age, 18);
end;
```

Comment: And if I have to break insert in the current table and make it into another table if condition is true?

Comment: @Darcky Use an `IF` statement that inserts into the other table and then raises an error to stop the current insert.

Comment: @Darcky But that will cause problems if you're inserting multiple rows into the table, since it will cancel the entire operation, preventing the request of the inserts. You should probably do this in your application logic rather than triggers.

Comment: But it breaks whole transaction

Comment: @Darcky . . . As far as I know, most databases treat an `insert` as a single transaction, even when there are multiple rows.  So all get inserted or none.  It might be possible to use `insert ignore` to avoid errors generated by the trigger.